# Common website phrases in multiple languages?

Tags: language, localization, internationalisation

Is there a resource anywhere that lists common web UI phrases in multiple languages?

I'm interested in having quick access to translations of phrases like `cancel`, `save`, `welcome`, and so on for quick prototyping of internationalized sites.

Obviously a site-wide contextual translation is necessary for a final product, but I'm interested in what I can do in my first pass over a design - it feels awful to just write nonsense into translation files, or copy/paste phrases I know are incorrect!

Comment: I would check various Linux branches - there are a lot of translations of standard terms to different languages. But perhaps it is not very well organized to see a translation to many languages at once (checked ubuntu launchpad just now).
Another option may be using Google translate, hope it can properly translate standard phrases.

Comment: Checking large sofwtare projects is a good idea. I'm always hesitant to use auto translation because I imagine standard phrases can have many different translations, and I have no way of asking the translator to give me 'no, when referring to a boolean setting' to avoid [do not want](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecursiveTranslation) :P.

Comment: @SergiyT. sorry, forgot to tag you in my response.

Comment: You can simply machine translate your resource file (po, resx, strings.xml etc.) if you are simply looking for pseudo translation for testing and design purposes. Google Translation toolkit can do that for you.

Comment: "I'm over 18" is surely one of those phrases :)

Comment: The Microsoft link no longer works. Does anyone have the link to where the page moved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft has their terminology online and for download:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language

This should contain all default things you need.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has moved its Terminology Dictionary here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language

Please mind this is not a simple list of default terms, but a translator of terms used in Microsoft application. Anyway, it's pretty good since it has a huge amount of words that might be used here and there.

There's also a download functionality I never used, but seems interesting too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56392)

Comment: Daniel Buckmaster asked for a resource with a list of the most common words could be used in web UI. My link seems an appropriate answer since contains what Daniel asked, according to my personal experience (I use that website when I'm in need of what Daniel needed).

Is there something I'm missing? If so, could you please be more specific about it?

Comment: good point. I focused on the first line.  I edited it.

Comment: Thanks for editing. This is my first post here, and I didn't want to write anything wrong or confusing.